# How to include workshops/hands-on sessions on CV?

Tags: phd, cv, physics, workshop

I'm in my second year of PhD in the field of astronomy and have recently been invited to a scientific meeting with about 20 people to give a 1:30h workshop/hands-on session about a certain simulation tool that has been developed in my research group.
The workshop inlcuded a 20 minutes presentation of general information and a 1:10h hands-on session with prepared code examples, that everyone could try out themselves.

The preparation took several days and, to me, it was quite a big thing, so I thought about listing it on my CV. The two questions I have now are the following:

1. Would you list something like this at all on your CV?
2. Where or how would you list this? I don't think it's quite on the level of a (invited) talk given at a conference, but I think this is probably the standard category that comes closest to it. Any opinions?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely put this on your resume!

It could be something complex like "Planned astronomy simulation workshop for 20 colleagues with a brief presentation of the simulation followed by hands-on work using my prepared sample code scripts."

Or it could be simpler like "demonstrated new astronomy simulation to 20 colleagues at a workshop."

You worked hard on it, it should show in your resume/CV.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I would probably list it. This is might be something that a late-career researcher would choose to omit or categorize differently (I'm not at the point in my career to comment on that with any actual experience though - that's just my gut impression). But I think it is valuable in building a resume as a student.

I would treat it like any other invited talk. The fact that it is at a smaller event doesn't really change that.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes
2. "I don't think it's quite on the level of a (invited) talk given at a conference": you are very right.

In fact preparing for a workshop is much more
demanding than invited talks at conferences. Invited talks are
"just" the sum of the work of the past n years and their personal
experience and anedoctes (both extremely useful, interesting and I
always enjoy them) of the speaker.

So I would suggest you to put it in the conference section, or to create a new workshop section (but please stress that you were actively contributing to the workshop, otherwise it may be read as "audience in the workshop").

Honestly, depending on the target of your CV,  I would even put it in the working experience or in the education part ... but surely, my general rule is that something that took more than one day to prepare for has definitely its place in one's CV!